# How can I check if an element is equal to none in another list of elements in Python?

Tags: python

I'm just getting started to Python, and I'm having an hard time figuring out something with `if` statements.

Say I have the following two lists:

```
one = [{'id': '2'}, {'id': 3}]
two = [{'id': '4'}, {'id': 5}]
```

I want to loop through `one` and compare the `id`s of `one` to `two`. Basically, what I want to find is if the two lists share an `id` with the same value. In this example, my code should return a `Not found`, because 2 is different from 4 and 5, and 3 is different from 4 and 5.

Basically, what i want to do is: check if `2` is equal to any `id` of `two`, if not, print something, then the same with `3`. In pseudo code it would be like this: IF there is no `id` in `two` EQUAL TO `2`, PRINT something. Then the same with `3` and so on.

I tried the following:

```
for x in one:
  for y in two:
    if x['id'] != y['id']:
      print('Not found')
```

The problem with this code is that it will return four `Not found`, because it's comparing every element. Instead, I simply want to check if there is a `2` or a `3` in `two`.

Comment: You don't know it is `Not found` until *after* you have checked them all; so you can't print that until *after* the loop completes.

Comment: `set(kv for d in one for kv in d.items()) & set(kv for d in two for kv in d.items())`

Comment: in this structure it has to loop through two lists to compare the each other.

Comment: You want to check for 2 possible elements in a list with 2 items. 2 * 2 = 4 does it not? Are you saying you not want a message printed for all 4 checks?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. Basically, what i want to do is: check if `2` is equal to any `id` of `two`, if not, print something, then the same with `3`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you've got what looks like an error in your code, you're using a string for the first ID and an integer for the second one.

There's several ways to check for intersection in python. [Here's an article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/) that goes over several different approaches. I like using the `set()` type, because it has a helpful built-in method called `intersection`. Sets are a bit different than lists, in that they cannot contain duplicates and are automatically sorted.

For example, you if you had a set that contained 1 and 2, i.e. `set1 = set([1,2])`, you could use `set1.intersection([2])` to check if 2 was within that set.

Here's how I would implement such functionality in your case (with all keys as integers):

```
one = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
two = [{'id': 4}, {'id': 5}]

def flatten(list_of_dicts):
    return [item['id'] for item in list_of_dicts]

intersecting_ids = set(flatten(one)).intersection(flatten(two))
```